# Getting latest facebook post via oembed read feature

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I've been working on a website that has synchronized news with its Facebook page equivalent.

The main idea is to display on website 3 latest post from owner's facebook page.

So far I've applied for an App Review to use function oEmbed Read and the permission has been granted.

I've been using Facebook's graph API with success but I need to specify a proper URL link to specific post.

What I would like is to skip the part where I need to provide an endpoint so it will be automatized. Both for posts as well as for videos.

Endly, the code will be run from JS component that is applied on the website.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You will need to make an API call to request the three latest post from the page, to get the URLs you need for the oEmbed endpoint.

Comment: @CBroe I am already aware of that. I was thinking of a way to make correct call to request. Do you know of any? Is the user access token necessary for that?

Comment: User token of a page admin, or a page token.